# Write data in short using java

Tags: java, arrays, short

I am trying write data into my serial port using java. For now I can only populate the data into a table form. Can I know are there any ways to write short data into the serial port.

This is my code:

```
    static short[] bytearray = {0x02, 0x08, 0x16, 0x00, 0x00, 0x33, 0xC6 , 0x1B};
    outputStream = serialPort.getOutputStream();
    outputStream.writeShort(bytearray);
    outputStream.flush();
```

I cannot use the write short at the outputstream write method. Can anyone help me with this. Thank you.

Comment: What is the type of `outputStream`? Why have you got a *short* array called `byteArray`? (Way to confuse things...) What error are you getting?

Comment: @JonSkeet I am sorry for the variable name. The error message I am getting is `short[] cannot be converted to int`. I am trying to write data into my serial port actually. This is my first time using Java serial port plugin. Can you help me with this pls.

Comment: Well, the error is clear, you're putting an array in a method that expects only one element! Loop through your array and write one element at a time into the stream.

Comment: @JPMoresmau do I have to do something like this? `for(int i=0; i<bytearray.length; i++){
                outputStream = serialPort.getOutputStream();
                outputStream.write(bytearray[i]);
                outputStream.flush();
            }` sorry for the indetations

Comment: Yes, that's the idea... If your array can have variable length, you may want to start with the length, but of course it depends what's expected at the other end.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand it the `writeShort` takes as a parameter an integer and sends two shorts to the port. So all you have to do is to convert two shorts into an int and call the method with it.

```
outputStream = serialPort.getOutputStream();
for (int i = 0; i < bytearray.length; i+=2) {
   outputStream.writeShort((bytearray[i + 1] << 16) | bytearray[i]);
}
outputStream.flush();
```

Note that this code hasn't been tested - use as an inspiration only! Especially the `bytearray[i + 1]` bit can throw index out of bounds!

Comment: sorry but the writeShort method it shows `cannot find symbol`

Comment: what happens if there is an uneven number of shorts?

Answer (score 0):

It should depend on who is reading the data you are writing to the serial port. If it is also a java program that you are developing, the easiest thing is to use a `ObjectOutputStream` to write your array of shorts and read it on the other side using an `ObjectInputStream`. On the other hand if the other side is a device, you need to worry about whether it accepts BigEndian or LittleEndian formats for the numbers. You can write a method to convert your array of shorts into a byte array and use `OutputStream#write`.